# Multiple command with xargs using sh -c is not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am trying to run this command

```
find . -name "new_impl.jar" | xargs -I '{}' sh -c 'java -jar jd-cli.jar --skipResources -n -g ALL '{}';'
```

it is not working and the error looks like it is not able to pick value of `'{}'`. When I am removing the section `sh -c` that help in running multiple command

```
find . -name "new_impl.jar" | xargs -I '{}' java -jar jd-cli.jar --skipResources -n -g ALL '{}';'
```

This command is working fine. I am using Oracle Linux 7. Can someone tell what is the reason behind this and if there is any other way to run multiple command.

Comment: Why use `xargs` at all? Just use `find ... -exec java -jar jd-cli.jar --skipResources -n -g ALL {} \;`.

Comment: This is actually shorter version of my command, I have 3-4 more commands to run after that that I have not shown here. If there is only command to run I would have followed yours command

Comment: This is my full command find . -name "new_impl.jar" | xargs -I '{}' sh -c 'java -jar jd-cli.jar --skipResources -n -g ALL '{}';rm '{}';mv *.jar '{}';unzip '{}' -d '{}'.bk/;rm '{}''

Comment: Your 2nd command is certainly NOT working fine, because it has unclosed quotes. Please post the output of `find . -name "new_impl.jar" | xargs -I '{}' sh -c 'printf "{%s}\n" "$@"' _ {}`, and the exact error you get when you replace `printf "{%s}\n"` in that with your `java -jar jd-cli.jar --skipResources -n -g ALL` command. Notice that `xargs` will replace the argument to `-I` even inside quotes; that `'...'{}';'` is absolutely pointless and will break your script.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend passing the file name as an argument to `sh`.

```
find . -name "new_impl.jar" | 
  xargs -I '{}' \
    sh -c 'java -jar jd-cli.jar --skipResources -n -g ALL "$1";rm "$1";mv *.jar "$1";unzip "$1" -d "$1".bk/;rm "$1"' _ {}
```

Note this will also work for using `-exec` from `find` instead.

```
find -name "new_impl.jar" \
   -exec sh -c 'java -jar jd-cli.jar --skipResources -n -g ALL "$1";rm "$1";mv *.jar "$1";unzip "$1" -d "$1".bk/;rm "$1"' _ {}
```

Comment: the error is that jd-cli.jar is expecting an input that it is not getting

Comment: and somehow it is immediately logging me off remote connection.

Comment: I think this sh -c is blocking me in Linux environment somehow because my same command works fine with MacOS